# Customizing HTML5 Boilerplate ( H5BP ) for PhoneGap / Cordova Project

Tags: html, cordova, html5boilerplate

Is there anyone who may suggest the good ideas if I want to use H5BP Mobile for My new PhoneGap Project? I really need to know-

1. How appropriate is the "H5BP Mobile" for "PhoneGap"?
2. What File should I remove from the H5BP?
3. What file/Scripts should I add to the boilerplate?
4. And Any other suggestion...

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but if anyone is looking for an HTML5 boilerplate for Cordova or Phonegap. I have three (3) available - with notes on decisions made and implementation details.

*Three (3) Phonegap Build Boilerplates for For Android and iOS*
http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-19.codesnippets.html

*An HTML Boilerplate for Phonegap*
http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html

Comment: Almost forgot this. I am gonna look into this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: And by the way, What is the best option to use instead of phone gaps in these days?